# MySql query to get two rows into one with latest data from one row

Tags: mysql, yii

Wondering if anyone could please help me with the following query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a49/1

This is the scenario:

A vehicle can be checkedout with a unique ra_no at any time. so a vehicle_id = 70 can be checkedout with ra_no = test with a branch_id and date_created and mileage.

It can then be checked back in with the same ra_no and then branch_id and date_created and mileage.

This query needs to return 1 row per ra_no for a vehicle_id eg. vehicle_id 70 and in this row it needs to display the currect status(latest) as well as the mileage(latest) and then the correct checked out date and location and correct checked in date and location.

You would group by ra_no but i cant seem to get the correct info out.

*This needs to be converted to a view so that i can create a model for it in Yii.*

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean converted to a view? Do you mean you want to create a view from the select statement? "What info do you expect to see from the select of the 4 items in the rental table?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79a49/16